# Frontend filters

Tags: filter, frontend, jhipster

Is there a possibility to add frontend UI elements to apply filters to the particular entity view (for example I want to select all entities that have particular country)? 
So far I've found nothing on UI side, only in swagger.
Do I have to implement those on my own?

Comment: Yes. There is no client side support for filtering at the moment. But it should be trivial to implement

Comment: Yes, it is... But if you have lets say 10 entity views than you have to write boilerplate code 10 times. Is there plans to add filter generators?

Comment: If you can do a PR for it i'm sure the jhipster team would be happy